# How do I disable/stop an accidental subrepo from my main repo?

Tags: version-control, github, twitter-bootstrap, versioning, repository

This is my current status:

1. I created a new repo in github `project`
2. Cloned the repo in my dev computer in `/project`
3. Cloned **twitter bootstrap** repo in `/project/public/`
4. Made some structural changes to my project
5. Committed and pushed the changes to github

Because I accidentally made the `/project/public` directory a subrepo of twitter bootrap, it doesn't recognize any of the changes made to it.

I tried removing the .git directory, but that didn't fix it.

What can I do to reclaim the public directory as part of my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a nice fix, but this is what I did to make it work:

1. Remove the .git directory from the subrepo (`/project/public/.git`)
2. Moved the `public` directory outside of the main repo
3. Committed and pushed the deletion to github
4. Added back the `public` directory to my project
5. Committed and pushed the changes to github

No all the files inside public are being tracked properly by my main repo.

To avoid this, you should remove the .git directory before committing.